# C# How can I pick up numbers that contains x number from List?

Tags: c#, list

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> Allnumber = new List<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            int dice = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Random number between 1 and 100 : {0}", dice);
            Allnumber.Add(dice);
            if (dice == 1)
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Allnumber : " + string.Join(" ", Allnumber));
        List<int> Odd = (from number in Allnumber where number % 2 != 0 select number).ToList();
        List<int> Even = new List<int>(from number in Allnumber where number % 2 == 0 select number);
        Console.WriteLine("Odd : " + string.Join(" ", Odd));
        Console.WriteLine("Even : " + string.Join(" ", Even));
```

I want to make a new list which includes 3 from Allnumber list.
It should be containing all the number that has 3(3, 13, 23, 33, 34, 36, 39,  43, 53...).
Anyway to pick up only 3s?
I found out there are Findall, Contain methods but cant use it for int type list.                                                                                                            THANK YOU EVERYONE cant believe that there are so many ways to do it :D

Comment: One thing unclear about your question. Do you mean *contains* 3 or *ends with* 3? ie, is `32` to be found?

Comment: oh yes comment from @Jamiec  changes the game :) if 32 is in your output list then answer would be different and needs string manipulation.

Comment: My spidey senses tells me the inputs here aren't as concise as they should be

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE
cant believe that there are so many ways to do it
:D

Comment: Didnt know that I cant accept all the answers

Comment: @JungminKoo you did well to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @JungminKoo you can't accept all the answer but you can Upvote all of them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would move this check in to a separate method

```
public static bool ContainsDigit(int input, int digit)
{
    do
    {
        if (input % 10 == digit)
        {
            return true;
        }
        input /= 10;
    }
    while (input > 0);
    return false;
}
```

usage:

```
List<int> result = Allnumber.Where(x => ContainsDigit(x, 3)).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ZPNbM

---

Same approach in one line

```
List<int> Allnumber = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
List<int> result = Allnumber.Where(x => { do { if (x % 10 == 3) return true; } while ((x /= 10) > 0); return false; }).ToList();
```

---

Performace (Allnumber with `1000000` numbers):

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| User       | Method                   | Time         |
|------------|--------------------------+--------------|
| fubo       | ContainsDigit()          | 0,03 seconds |
| JamieC     | ToString().Contains("3") | 0,20 seconds |
| TheGeneral | WhereDigit()             | 0,10 seconds |
| TheGeneral | InternalRun()            | 0,04 seconds |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

dotnetfiddle doesn't really work with benachmarking - it varies a bit each run probably because of the load of dotnetfiddle and I can only use `100,000` instead of `1,000,000` numbers but ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/pqCx2J

Comment: Heck I upvoted this long before the OP accepted my answer.

Comment: I didn't know that this gives you such an performance boost. Great

Comment: Backs up the point in my answer that mine gets progressively slower as the list increases. Its un-noticable with 100,000 but very noticable with 1,000,000. Don't do string manipulation kids!

Comment: @Jamiec [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) :)

Comment: haha yeah ive seen that. Its when the numbers come from a super-slow database query and then you try to optimize this algorithm to squeeze 0.001s out of it. Fun fun.

Comment: Yield will be muxh slower as it has to produce the whole list of digits in this instance . However it goes to show how to 100 nerds occupied for an hour

Comment: If you are bored, i just added 2 more versions, if you feel like benchmarking. I still don't think they are a fast as yours though

Comment: @TheGeneral done https://dotnetfiddle.net/vYEiCm almost the same, i've issues with unmanaged code so I've just added the 1st one. Feel free to update my answer.

Comment: hah kewl, well if we ever need jobs in finding the number 3, we have it sorted

Comment: Ahh its all good, unsafe wont run on .net fiddle, its only slightly faster. but it was just a bit of fun when i got home from work, now its time for beer

Comment: Yeah i think you are right there, the first method i had was going through them all, and then doing a contains

Comment: Also this can go parallel , heh, anyway thats enough finding 3 for today

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here is a `yield` version and `IEnumerable` extension method

```
public static class StupidExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Digits(int input)
    {
        do yield return input % 10; while ((input /= 10) > 0);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> WhereDigit(this IEnumerable<int> source, int digit) 
              => source.Where(x => Digits(x).Contains(digit));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = Allnumber.WhereDigit(3);
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EzmahA)

---

Here are 2 more

```
protected override IEnumerable<int> InternalRun(IEnumerable<int> values, int digit)
{
   var ary = values.ToArray();
   var result = new List<int>();
   fixed (int* pAry = ary)
   {
      for (var p = pAry; p < pAry + ary.Length; p++)
         for (var d = *p; d > 0; d /= 10)
            if (d % 10 == digit){ result.Add(*p); break;}
   }  
}

protected override IEnumerable<int> InternalRun(IEnumerable<int> values, int digit)
{
   foreach (var val in values)
      for (var d = val; d > 0; d /= 10)
         if (d % 10 == digit)
            yield return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I found out there are Findall, Contain methods but cant use it for int type list.

These are string methods, which can can use, you just need to convert your number to a string as part of the `where` clause

```
 List<int> HasThrees = (from number in Allnumber where number.ToString().Contains("3") select number).ToList();
```

But this is *far* from the most efficient way to solve this problem. It will perform fine for small lists, but get progressively slower as the length of your list increases.

For a more efficient solution look at one of the answers that do this without converting the numbers to a string.

Answer (score 2):

First convert all numbers in the `Where` clause to strings with `ToString` and then use `Contains` to get the list of all the numbers that contain the number 3:

```
var result = Allnumber.Where(x => x.ToString().Contains("3")).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to check if remainder is 3 after dividing it by 10 i.e. n%10 == 3.

```
IEnumerable<int> allThrees =
    from num in Allnumber
    where num%10 == 3
    select num;
```

This solution works on the based of examples OP has included, after reading a comment I realize if question is about all 3s like 31,32. Then string manipulation might be the solution.

Comment: yeah I just noticed ! Good solution thought about posting that too. !

Comment: fails at `31,32,34,35,36,37,38,39`

Comment: That's what mentioned in answer @fubo. See the examples given in OP.